# I would like to know best way to access azure resource from on prem dotnet app

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using DefaultAzureCredential library to authenticate against azure to use key vault and my app is deployed in on prem. So right now I am using client id/secrete stored in environment variable of server. I don't want to store any kind of secret in environment variable. Is there any other approach by which I can access key vault in my on prem app without storing client id/secret in environment variable. If some one has access to server they can see that environment variable so I want to avoid that.   I know if app is deployed in azure then I can enable managed identity but in my case it is on prem app and i registered that app in azure.

I dont want to store clientid/secret in environment variable. I would like to know any other approach by which this should get clientid.secret in memory and use that. I also dont want to store encrypted version of secret in environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I think [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential) can help you to check if you can or can't do it.

[image]

I think using Powershell to `Connect-AzAccount` a user in your on prem server can be an option, but this means your app are trying to access the Azure key vault on behalf of the user, so you also need to add the [access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) for this user in Azure key vault page.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny Wang for giving option,  That is one option like I need to do onetime activity in server which is login in powershell with that service principle so DefaultAzureCredential will use that for authentication. But in that case If password for Service principle change then again I need to relogin. Good option but still searching some other option.

Comment: even you stored client secrets, you still need  to pay attentition to the secret expired time.... anyway thank you for your reply.